# use * with a batch file to get filenames

Tags: batch-file, window

I am using Windows XP and need to create a batch file to move tok.filename to filename.tok. 
This works for one file if I type in `fix.bat tok.filename`.

```
set filename=%1
set newname=%filename:~4,45%
ren %1 %newname%.tok
```

I need to type in `fix.bat tok*`, but this puts `tok*` in the filename.

How do I get it to read all the files into the filename one at a time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `for` statement.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%i in (tok.*) do (
  set filename=%%i
  set newname=!filename:~4,45!
  ren %%i !newname!.tok
)
```

Enabling the delayed expansion makes it so that the variables are evaluated at the time they are used.

Alternatively, since you already have a batch file that works, you could write another batch file that uses the `for` statement, which calls your working batch file -- like this:

```
for %%i in (tok.*) do call fix.bat %%i
```

Or you could run it directly from the command line like this:

```
for %i in (tok.*) do call fix.bat %i
```

Comment: +1, Good, but can be improved. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12593670/1012053)

Comment: @dbenham - It's true that a lot of other variables could be considered in the solution (as noted in your answer), but the OP said their existing batch file was already working as needed except they had to manually type each filename, which implies that all of the other considerations are not an issue.

Comment: Thanks, this works great for what I need to do. I just added a bit more so it would change to each directory and then change all the filenames from the unix filepro format to the windows filepro format.

Answer (score 2):

No need for a batch script

```
for %F in (tok.*) do for /f "delims=." %X in ("%~xF") do ren "%F" "%X.%~nF"
```

Double up the percents if used within a batch script.

The above may not give the desired result if more than one `.` appears in a file name.

For example `tok.part1.part2` would become `part2.tok.part1`.

If you want `part1.part2.tok` instead, then you can use the following simple script.

```
@echo off
ren tok.* .*?.tok
for %%F in (.*.tok) do for /f "tokens=* delims=." %%A in ("%%F") do ren "%%F" "%%A"
```

For an explanation of how that 1st REN works in the 2nd script, see [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

I suppose an esoteric argument could be made that a name like `tok..name` would become `name.tok` when it should be `.name.tok`. That could be fixed by using:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
ren tok.* .*?.tok
for %%F in (.*.tok) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!name!" "!name:~1!"
  endlocal
)
```

The nice thing about the solutions above is they don't rely on the length of "tok". A string value of any length could be substituted for "tok" and the code works just as well.

The James L solution works well for a constant length. That solution can be improved a bit.

- The 2nd argument to the substring operation is not needed. Removing it lets the solution work no matter how long the full original name is.
- The code will fail if a name has an `!` in it. Fixed by toggling delayed expansion on and off.
- The filenames should be quoted in the REN statement in case of spaces or special characters

.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for %%i in (tok.*) do (
  set "filename=%%i"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  ren "!filename!" "!filename:~4!.tok"
  endlocal
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the same without delayed expansion (which is slow).
Also, if there is only one dot, without explicitly using lengths of name parts.
%~n expands to filename without extension, and %~x to dot with extension (so I remove dot with `:~1`).

Also, using %* in for, you may pass arbitrary number of arguments.

And even more. If you add /R bewteen for and %%I (you'll get `for /R %%I`), it will recurse into subdirs also.

Whole batch file:

```
for %%I IN (%*) do call :Rename "%~I"
exit /b

:Rename
    set newname=%~x1
    ren %1 "%~dp1%newname:~1%.%~n1"
exit /b
```